# Caching images, CSS and JS resources in Wicket 1.5.3

Tags: performance, caching, wicket

I am trying to optimize the performance of a Wicket 1.5.3 application.

I'm trying to get the caching configuration up and running. I've already reviewed "migration to 1.5" papers, the migration guide and samples. I've also ensured that there is a default caching strategy available, and tried to set a custom one.

```
getResourceSettings().setCachingStrategy(strat);
```

The app has CSS and JS in a Base-Frame.html header as link and script, and it has a lot of images. I'm currently using something like this:

```
Image img = new Image("logoutImg") {
    protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
        super.onComponentTag(tag);
        tag.put("src", baseUrl + "/images/logout.png");
    }
};
```

With that, the HTTP header output is always:

> Pragma No-cache
>   Cache-Control no-cache

for all resources and pages.

I've now implemented some servlet filters, which is a rather brutish method that avoids all previously set Wicket headers.

Could anyone provide a running working example, or some tips for getting this up and running? In particular, something using `FilenameWithVersionResourceCachingStrategy` would be really helpful, since that seems to be a good solution.

Comment: Currently we have solved our problem by externalizing all those resources into a Content Accelerator Framework (CAF).

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to use Wicket's `CachingImage` class allowing you to set the headers accordingly to the browser

Comment: i would have to try... do you know already that this is working ?